# javascript UI testing framework with event simulation

Tags: javascript, jquery, user-interface, automated-tests, frontend

I am looking for a framework to simulate mouse drag and drop of various html tags via jquery then capture the screen and compare that with a saved image. I do this in order to test a webpage UI.

I've seen a great post: [Javascript testing to simulate drag for JQuery UI sortable lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7116149/javascript-testing-to-simulate-drag-for-jquery-ui-sortable-lists), which gave this link: https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/blob/master/tests/jquery.simulate.js

Currently I am not sure how I can use jquery.simulate.js (but I'm playing with it to learn), so I am interested if there are any other frameworks that I can use (perhaps some that look more **like JUnit/NUnit**).

Preferably I'd like to do be able to code sth like this:

```
simulateDivDrag(Image expectedResult){
  simulate mouse drag  of event
  take screenshot
  cmp(expectedResult, screenshot)
}
```

I remember reading that Firefox has built an in house tool for such automated UI testing so it's definitely possible.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

If you are using jUnit, you probably want to use [Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/) which can automated user actions in multiple browsers.

Comment: it's for a .NET website; I mentioned those unit tests because I am very familiar w them since I do backend work. Can Selenium be integrated with any website?

Comment: And there is nUnit and if you read the Selenium's site you would see it is available in a [bunch of languages](http://seleniumhq.org/download/).