# How to test Drag and Drop behavior with Selenium IDE ?

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, selenium, drag-and-drop, jquery-ui-sortable

I've implemented tables with JQuery UI's sortable feature, but I can't figure out how to test it in Selenium IDE.

I didn't find a working anwser there : [How to test a JQuery UI Sortable widget using Selenium?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4195352/how-to-test-a-jquery-ui-sortable-widget-using-selenium)

There's also an helper plugin https://github.com/mattheworiordan/jquery.simulate.drag-sortable.js
But it would be better directly in Selenium.

Does anyone have a clue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to simulate Drag and Drop behaviour to test it in Selenium IDE, here's a not exhaustive list of what you can do to simulate that :

1) mouseDownAt(locator, coordString) - here you press down left mouse button and hold it

2) sometimes it is useful to wait for reaction (e.g. wait for data to be loaded in the DOM). At least put small pause to be sure that mouse "captured" the object and can drag it (tests running time is often not comparable to an human using a website)

3) mouseMoveAt(locator, coordinate) - drag where you need

4) mouseUpAt(locator, coordString) - release your mouse button finishing drag and drop

Try to experiment with different mouse speed by setting different values and wait (e.g. after mouseDownAt) by changing locators and putting pause depending the context of your project application.

You may also add in the beginning of these steps setMouseSpeed(pixels) to make the mouse move slowly (to be sure it can drag) and in the end setMouseSpeed back to its default value (default is 10 meaning that mouse step is 10 pexels. Setting speed 3-5 pixels will make the mouse move slower).